# Array length is 0 from the response of an async await call

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've spent a considerable amount of time trying to debug this issue but it might stem from my lack of knowledge of how async/await works with TypeScript/JavaScript. I'm fetching items stored in browser storage from a function that returns a promise and then I check to see if the .length is > 0 or not. If I do a log of the object returned from `GetReminders` then I can see there are definitely items in there but then why is `reminders.length == 0` true?

```
export class ViewTrialsView {

    static async render() {
        let trialManager : TrialReminderManager = new TrialReminderManager();
        let spinner = document.getElementById("spinner");
        spinner.classList.add("is-active");

        let remindersContainer = document.getElementById("reminders_container");

        console.log("Rendering trials list markup...");
        const reminders = await trialManager.GetReminders();
        console.log(reminders);
        spinner.classList.remove("is-active");

        if (reminders.length == 0) {
            remindersContainer.innerText = "No reminders found.";
            return;
        }

        const markup = 
            `
            <ul class="mdl-list">
                ${reminders.map(((reminder, index) => `
                    <li class="mdl-list__item mdl-list__item--two-line">
                        <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
                            <span>${reminder.Name}</span>
                            <span class="mdl-list__item-sub-title">${reminder.ExpirationDate}</span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="mdl-list__item-secondary-content">
                            <a class="mdl-list__item-secondary-action href="#" id='${reminder.Id.toString()}'>
                                <i class="material-icons">cancel</i>
                            </a>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                `))}
            `;
        remindersContainer.innerHTML = markup;

    }
}

export class TrialReminderManager {
    public AddReminder(trial : Trial) : void {
        var key = trial.Id.toString();
        window.browser.storage.sync.set({[key] : trial}, () => {
            console.log(`Added new trial ${trial} with id ${trial.Id.toString()}.`);
        })
    }

    public async GetReminders() : Promise<Array<Trial>> {
        console.log("Getting reminders from browser storage.");

        let reminders = new Array<Trial>();
        window.browser.storage.sync.get(null, (items) => {
            Object.keys(items).forEach(
                reminder => reminders.push(items[reminder]));
        });

        return Promise.resolve(reminders);
    }
}
```

Edit: The code was almost there, I suppose the pattern for returning a Promise from a function that has a callback is to resolve the promise inside the callback like so.

```
public async GetReminders() : Promise<Array<Trial>> {
        return new Promise<Array<Trial>>((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log("Getting reminders from browser storage.");

            let reminders = new Array<Trial>();
            window.browser.storage.sync.get(null, (items) => {
                Object.keys(items).forEach(
                    reminder => reminders.push(items[reminder]));
                    resolve(reminders)
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure `reminders` is an array? It could be quite stupid because your code seems fine. Can you post the content of `reminders`?

Comment: Doesn't look like you're waiting for `window.browser.storage.sync.get()` to resolve. The `resolve(reminders)` should be inside that callback, just after the `forEach`. You should also be returning a promise, ie `return new Promise(resolve => { /* your code here */ })`

Comment: Are you sure you're using `storage.sync.get()` correctly? It returns a promise and I don't see a second _callback_ arg in the docs

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

It has a callback function there.

Comment: I was reading [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/get). In any case, the issue is the same

Comment: Thanks Phil, I was able to solve it with your comments.